# Please explain Theorem 4 in What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm reading [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1405). And I found an interesting Theorem: (If you have already read this article, you can skip to the last paragraph.)

---

**Theorem 4**

If ln(1 + x) is computed using the formula:

[image]

the relative error is at most 5ε when 0 ≤ x < 3/4, provided subtraction is performed with a guard digit, e < 0.1, and ln is computed to within 1/2 ulp.

This formula will work for any value of x but is only interesting for x << 1 , which is where catastrophic cancellation occurs in the naive formula ln(1 + x). Although the formula may seem mysterious, there is a simple explanation for why it works. Write ln(1 + x) as

[image].

The left hand factor can be computed exactly, but the right hand factor µ(x) = ln(1 + x)/x will suffer a large rounding error when adding 1 to x. However, µ is almost constant, since ln(1 + x) ≈ x. So changing x slightly will not introduce much error. In other words, if x̄ ≈ x, computing xμ(x̄) will be a good approximation to xµ(x) = ln(1 + x). Is there a value for x̄ for which x̄ and x̄ + 1 can be computed accurately? There is; namely x̄ = (1 [image] x) [image] 1, because then 1 + x̄ is exactly equal to 1 [image] x.

---

According to the author, 1 + x̄ is **exactly** equal to 1 [image] x. This confused me: When x is very small, adding x to 1 should cause the loss of the information in the low order bits of x. Also, there will be a catastrophic cancellation in (1 [image] x) [image] 1, which will cause many of the accurate digits to disappear.

So please tell me, why 1 + x̄ is **exactly** equal to 1 [image] x in this Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to re-read the definitions of x̄ and [image: +]. x̄  is a value near x which has no low bits to lose. Therefore, 1+x̄  is exact, and the same as the rounded result 1[image: +]x

Comment: What actually concerns me is that (1 (+) x (-) 1) may yield something irrelevant, due to catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: @sunqingyao: When you compute fp(1+x), you get exactly 1+xbar for some xbar within eps/2 of x.  Since 0 <= x <= 1, when you compute fp(fp(1+x)-1), you get fp(1+x)-1 = 1+xbar-1 = xbar.  The point here is to account for the effects of "catastrophic cancellation."  Recall Sterbenz's theorem that subtraction of two floating-point numbers within a factor 2 of each other is exact.

Comment: @tmyklebu So whatever xbar's value is, the only requirement is that it must be similiar to x, right?

Comment: @sunqingyao: I see three requirements.  First, xbar is a floating point number.  Second, xbar is close to x.  Third, 1+xbar is also a floating-point number---that is, no roundoff occurs when computing fp(1+xbar).

Comment: @tmyklebu "no roundoff occurs when adding 1 to xbar" This is exactly the original anthor's purpose.